# Selenium 2: something wrong with “driver.findElement(By....);

Tags: java, eclipse, firefox, selenium-webdriver

the selenium webDriver just does nothing when no Element is found by calling `driver.findElement(By.className("item"));`
the driver does not even throw an ElementNotfoundException, which I´m sometimes expecting. it just hangs.
here is an example:

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("default");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get(APP_ADDRESS);

WebElement sBoxPopup = driver.findElement(By
                .className("item"));
...
```

the driver is hanging at driver.findElement(...). It hangs even if I remove the implicitlyWait.
I´m searching for the error since 4 days. I hope someone can give a hint.
I´m using Firefox 17.0.1 and selenium-java/-server 2.28. I also downgraded the selenium version to 2.25 just nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try lowering your firefox version to 16 and try.

Answer (score 0):

Try with driver.findelement(By.xpath("//*[@class='date']")
Mostly className will not work if classname will contain space "da te".

Comment: There is no space in my xpath string!

Comment: try it ::  driver.findelement(By.xpath("//*[@class='item']")

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the xpath itself, because in your web page there may be more number of times "class=item". try changing the xpath by finding some unique string in your web page.